# Why booting up docker container using blimp throws an error?

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

When I boot up a container with below configuration using Blimp (Docker Compose in a cloud), it throws an error `Exited: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "chdir to cwd (\"/var/www/html\") set in config.json failed: permission denied": unknown`. Booting with docker-compose works just fine.

The problem is with volume mounting as far as I know.

*docker-compose.yml*

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    container_name: app
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        user: mk
        uid: 1000
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - ./docker/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - app
      - mysql
    networks:
      - default
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_DATABASE: homestead
      MYSQL_USER: homestead
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
    volumes:
      - ./docker/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - default
networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
```

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

LABEL MAINTAINER="Mayur Shingrakhiya <mk.shingrakhiya@gmail.com>"

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html

ARG user=mk
ARG uid=1000

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git curl libpng-dev libonig-dev libxml2-dev zip unzip

RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath exif gd mbstring opcache pcntl pdo_mysql

# Get the Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

ENV PHP_OPCACHE_VALIDATE_TIMESTAMPS="1"
ENV PHP_OPCACHE_MAX_ACCELERATED_FILES="10000"
ENV PHP_OPCACHE_MEMORY_CONSUMPTION="192"
ENV PHP_OPCACHE_MAX_WASTED_PERCENTAGE="10"

COPY ./docker/php/conf.d/opcache.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/opcache.ini

# Create a User
RUN useradd -G www-data,root -u $uid -d /home/$user $user
RUN mkdir -p /home/$user/.composer && chown -R $user:$user /home/$user
RUN chmod -R 775 /var/www/html

WORKDIR /var/www/html

USER $user
```

You won't find anything related to Blimp as it is not yet publicly released.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: When you bind-mount a host directory over `/var/www/html`, it brings all of its permissions and (numeric) ownership with it; the `chmod` line at the end has no effect, and if the host user with uid 1000 can't access the directory, you'll get that error.  Can you `COPY` the application code in the Dockerfile, and delete the `volumes:`?

Comment: If I delete the `volumes:`, it does boot up, but `COPY` has no effect. I changed the `uid` to match with the user of the host machine and still getting this error. I have another working container for `nginx` which mounts the same directory. Updated the `docker-compose.yml`.

Answer (score -2):

can you try RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html and then see if u get this error ?

Comment: i say this to debug the n we can talk .